# Average is higher than 75th percentile

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, order-statistics

I have a statistical question with mean, median and percentile.

I have run my data with over thousand samples. From this run, I can see that the Average result value is higher than the median and percentile 75th value...
This seems my data is right skewed.

What else can I deduct from about my results?

Details on the results: average = 2.5, percentile 75 = 2 and median = 1, max= 11
A valid result could be anything from 0 up to anything.

Comment: *Bell/normal curve* and *arithmetic mean is sensitive to outliers* and so on .... are ideas that cross me mind.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the values *seem* to be integers. (Assuming they are), zeros can not be more than half of the data set. and more than 3/4 of it are either 0, 1 or 2. The simplest data producing this results would be like $\left[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 11\right]$. Not much more to see there, methinks.